# Problems after undo a push

Tags: git

After pushing something wrongly I undo it using:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

After that, the number of the log is in the prompt. How can i remove that?

Also, now when I try to commit now, I get this error:

> Not currently on any branch

Comment: You're in detached mode, try `git checkout master`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the number of the log is in the prompt". Can you explain?

Comment: @me_and for me the number of the log is the number releated of each commit, this kind 95ada058a1a5a78af7a542ed66e67ddb5c79ef6d

Comment: But what do you mean by "is in the prompt"? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @me_and the prompt is like this: `(95ada...)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [rlegendi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981284/rlegendi) mentioned, you have to call `git checkout <branchname>` to get out of detached mode.

If you want to remove the last commit from the repository you pushed it to previously, you will have to call `git push -f` to enforce the push.

But beware: Others which previously pulled your accidentally pushed commit can have to rebase their local branch (see "Hard case" of [recovering_from_upstream_rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase))

To give some example, consider that

1. you and your collaborator(s) are working on branch *master*,
2. you pushed it to the remote repo referenced as *origin*.
3. You removed the very last commit on origin's master and
4. the collaborators pulled the old version where it was still present.

In this case, they have to execute

```
git fetch origin
git rebase --onto origin/master master
```

In another case, where collaborators had *n* additional commit on top of the one which was removed in origin, they have to execute

```
git fetch origin
git rebase --onto origin/master master~n
```